# Similar function to Sinc function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, examples-counterexamples

I am interested in a function which at $x=0$ starts from approximately $1$ and as you go on it decreases periodically to $0$ in a similar fashion to the [Sinc function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function).

Comment: Divide $\sin$ by a monotonically increasing function.

Comment: How about $$\frac{2-2\cos x}{x^2}$$

Comment: The Bessel function of the first kind of order 0, $J_0(x)$ has this property.

Comment: @Bitrex The first spherical Bessel function j0(x) is also known as the (unnormalized) sinc function. Found this on Wikipedia

Comment: @Sebastian That's true.  I think the difference is that while the spherical Bessel functions can be expressed in terms of elementary functions, the regular Bessel functions can only be expressed as power series/integral, etc.

Comment: @Sebastian Do you have a particular application for this required function in mind?